# Getting an error in line 5 saying "improper operator" in Matlab code

Tags: matlab

I'm getting an error in line 5 and I don't understand how to fix it. Its 
supposed to use Lagrange interpolation for the n values and 
functions listed.

```
x_plot = linspace(0,1,512);
n = 4;
x = linspace(0,1,n+1) ;
y = sin(2 * pi * x) ;
Ln_1_4 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x);
y1 = sin(2 * pi * x_plot);

n = 8;
x = linspace(0,1,n+1) ;
y = sin(2 * pi * x) ;
Ln_1_8 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x);

n = 16;
x = linspace(0,1,n+1) ;
y = sin(2 * pi * x) ;
Ln_1_16 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x);

n = 4;
x = linspace(0,1,n+1) ;
y = abs(x-.05) ;
Ln_2_4 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x)
y2 = abs(x_plot - .5);
n = 8;
x = linspace(0,1,n+1) ;
y = abs(x-.05) ;
Ln_2_8 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x);

n = 16;
x = linspace(0,1,n+1) ;
y = abs(x-.05) ;
Ln_2_16 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x);

plot(x_plot,y1,x_plot,Ln_1_4,'r--',x_plot,Ln_1_8,'g:');

function Ln = lag(x_plot,n,y,x)
Ln = 0;
for j = 1:n
    Ln_k = 1;
    for i = 1:n
       if i!=j
       Ln_k = (x_plot-x(i))/(x(j)-x(i)).*Ln_k

    end
    Ln = Ln + y(j)*Ln_k
end
```

Comment: Which line is line 5? `Ln_1_4 = lag(x_plot,n,y,x);`? Does the function `lag()` actually exist? Indeed [`lag()` is a very different function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lag.html).

Comment: for me line 5 ran without errors, you have to replace != with ~=

Comment: It looks like your script function is missing an `end`, possibly closing the `if`. Is this being run in MATLAB or Octave? If it's Octave, does moving the function definition to the top of the file (possibly with a needed null statement like `1;` so the runtime doesn't think it's a function file) change things?

Comment: It's line 5 in the lag function, which as Yuval has pointed out uses != instead of ~=. Also an end is missing on line 7.

Comment: I think you have your answer here, but next time, please copy-paste the full error message, don’t paraphrase it. The error message is very descriptive and pinpoints exactly what and where is wrong.